# Custom Class Attributes in Metro Style App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, custom-attributes, system.reflection, portable-class-library

I am trying to define and retrieve custom attributes on a class in a Metro Style App portable library.

Something like

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class FooAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[Foo]
public class Bar
{
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var attrs = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>(typeof(Bar));
    }
}
```

This works in ordinary 4.5, but in a portable library targetting metro style apps it tells me

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
```

Thanks

Comment: Apparently, you need to do 

    var attrs = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>(typeof(Bar).GetTypeInfo());

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh535795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @user1364325 if the code in your above comment solves the problem, please post it as an answer and mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or, too leverage extensions as they were meant:

```
var attr = typeof(Bar).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the OP:

> You need to do var attrs = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Bar).GetTypeIn‌​fo());

This seems to agree with [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292%28v=vs.110%29)